# What if i have activation function that computes negative values?

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I have a rather simple question related to neural networks regarding activation functions. Mainly all the activations have a positive y value for a given training example

y = A(WX + b)  where y is somewhat always positive for large values.

Now my question is what will happen if my activation is somewhat like this

y = - (2, x)

Will will happen in the neural network if I use this activation or maybe an activation function that moves in the negative y-direction for all positive x values.

Your answer will be appreciated, please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't understand `y = - (2, x)` function

Comment: @RishabhGupta y = - min(2,x) *

Answer (score 0):

If in a existing, already trained neural network, if you take one of the nodes and change it's activation function, then you might not get the results you expected. If you are training from scratch and using activation functions like sigmoid (which have y range of -1 to 1) then after training it may very well happen that for some of the nodes the activation function moves in the negative y-direction for all positive x values. It all depends on the W and b parameter that are decided by the training. In such a case the neural network will run normally and give expected results, no problem will occur due to an activation function which moves in negative direction for positive inputs.